# Handling multiple Date segments in Json.net

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, json.net

I have an API endpoint that is expecting something similar to the following in the request:

```
{
...
  "BirthDay":"12",
  "BirthMonth":" "1",
  "BirthYear":"1986",
...
}
```

Now, I know that it is possible to do this by ignoring a datetime element when serializing:

```
public class Employee
{
...
    [JsonIgonore]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    internal string BirthDay
    {
        get { return BirthDate.Day.ToString(); }
    }

    internal string BirthMonth
    {
        get { return BirthDate.Month.ToString(); }
    }

    internal string BirthYear
    {
        get { return BirthDate.Year.ToString(); }
    }
...
}
```

The problem here is that the date formatting occurs frequently in the API like this. It would be much less code to write if I could use an attribute on the `DateTime` property. Could I use `JsonConverter` or `JsonProperty` or something similar to accomplish this?

Comment: A JsonConverter should do. Just keep the BirthDate property (with JsonIgnore and without the other three properties). In the WriteJson method of the converter first serialize your object into a JObject, then add your three JsonProperties to it (with values obtained from BirthDate) , and then finally write the JObject to the JsonWriter. Deserialization in the ReadJson method would work analoguous: First deserialize the given JObject to your object instance, then extract the three custom Birth* JsonProperties from the JObject and create+assign the BirthDate DateTime...

Comment: @elgonzo Would `JsonConvert` work for writing multiple json properties to the root object?

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether i understand you correctly. Do you want to serialize an object to a Json object and while doing so manipulate the Json data *outside* of the serialized object? (If so, rethink your approach. Something is very, very wrong about this...)

Comment: You would need to create a converter for the entire `Employee` type rather than just the `BirthDate` property I reckon.  If that seems like a pain (and it might well), you might be able to use a custom `ContractResolver`.